# How to specify only for the new added row in datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable, asp.net-ajax

Currently I'm using `forEach` that will execute the code for every row by row of the datatable. My problem now is, how can I execute the code only for a specific row that newly added and ignoring the previously added row?

```
function InStockk() {
          _datatableData.forEach(function (rowData) {
              var ID = rowData.ID;

              var quantity = parseInt($("#txtQuantity" + ID).val(), 10);
              if (!quantity) { quantity = 0; }

              var id = $("#txtItem"+ID).select2("val");
              console.log("stock id :" + id);

             $.ajax({
               url: "../WS/wsQuotation.asmx/GetStockInfo",
               type: 'GET',
               data: {
                   StockID: id ,
               },
               success: function (data) {

                   var json = JSON.parse(data);

                   var instock = parseFloat(json[0]["Inventory_Quantity"]);

                   $("#txtStock" + ID).val(instock - quantity);

               },
              error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText + ":  " + error);
               }
              });
         });
    }
```

Comment: you can have a new bool field which will have old or new and you run your code only for new and then set it to old once run. or if you have a datetime field then you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding a new row using [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) API method, then you can use something like:

```js
var rowData = { /* row data */ };
var row = table.row.add(rowData).draw();

_datatableData = [ rowData ];
InStockk();
```